# getTriggeringLocation always returns null

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have a problem coming along with Android Fused Location API. I have an IntentListener service that I need to receive locations periodically. I create and connect GoogleApiClient successfully, then I request to receive location updates through PendingIntent, but every time I call `GeofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation` the return value is always null.

Here's the code:

```
private void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

private void startLocationListener(Context context) {
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No Google Play Services.");
        return;
    }

    createLocationRequest();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

private void startLocationUpdates(Context context) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, IntentListener.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, pi);
    Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "INTEEENT");
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(Actions.ACTION_START_INTENT_LISTENER.equals(action)) {
        init(this);
    }
    else {
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if(event == null) Log.d(TAG, "Null event");
        if(event.getTriggeringLocation() == null) Log.d(TAG, "null location"); // **<-- PROBLEM HERE**
        if (event == null || event.getTriggeringLocation() == null) {
            return;
        }

        Location location = event.getTriggeringLocation();
        Log.d(TAG, "LocationC: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

And here's the manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.srn.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.srn.app.IntentListener"></service>
</application>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I'm running the app in x86 emulator with Android 5.1 installed.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geofencing API must be specifically registered via [GeofencingApi.addGeofences()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi#addGeofences(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)). Assuming you actually want to receive the location information from the `requestLocationUpdates()` call you are doing, you should use [LocationResult.extractResult()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult#extractResult(android.content.Intent)) in place of `GeofencingEvent.fromIntent()`.

An alternative for older versions of Google Play services is to use the key [KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED) to extract just a single location from the Intent:

```
Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(
    LocationServices.FusedLocationProviderApi.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. I'll try this evening when I get home :)

Comment: Strange. There is no LocationResult class in com.google.android.gms.location package. Maybe they changed something..?

Comment: Maybe you're using an older version of Google Play services? The latest is 7.5

Comment: I have revision 25 installed. I'm not sure which version it is, but revision 24 corresponds to 7.3. so it probably is 7.5 because there's no updates in SDK Manager.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio / Gradle, you should check your `build.gradle` file - just because it is installed doesn't mean your app automatically updates its dependency to the latest version.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the tip :). I upgraded Google Play services in my project, but the emulator has an older version 6.7.74 even though I have latest version installed in avd manager. Any idea how to upgrade google play services in emulator? Thanks again :)

Comment: Looks like I'm stuck with 6.7.74 until google updates android images. Is there any way to acquire location with this version of play services?

Comment: Added an alternate method to retrieve the location from the intent which I believe will work on Google Play services 6.7.74.

Comment: It worked. :) Thank you very much, I was already desperete :)) BTW, is it possible to receive more than one location in a single hit? And if so, would you mind telling me how do I enumerate in all those locations? Thanks again :)

Comment: Not with the Google Play services 6.5 SDK - batching location updates was introduced in [Google Play services 7.3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/theres-lot-to-explore-with-google-play.html) which is probably also when you get to start using `LocationResult.extractResult()` which returns a list of locations you can enumerate through.